# GET data using Ajax and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get

I have a problem. I am a beginer.I am curently struggling with `get` and `print` (or show in alert) data from another webside.

Am I on a good way?

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://www.ogimet.com/cgi-bin/getsynop?begin=201511201200&state=Pol&lang=eng&block=12100",
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(res) {
        var text = res.responseText;
    }
});
alert(text);
```

Any idea? Ogimet provides a SYNOP data. Than I will want to parse it, but now Iam doing something wrong cos I cant get this data.

Comment: Http cors problem.Allow cross domain request.

Comment: Is http://www.ogimet.com an external website?

Comment: please check your browser console. Getting cors error.

Comment: yes its a external webside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery ajax is asynchronous function call,

so  your alert code will be in callback function.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://www.ogimet.com/cgi-bin/getsynop?begin=201511201200&state=Pol&lang=eng&block=12100",
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(res) {
        console.log(res);
        // var text = res.responseText;
        // alert(text);
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok, thank you. It is one step foward, now I can get alert, but it is empty.

Comment: @EdytaB try console.log(res) instead of alert and see the ourput in console

Comment: it looks like something  is going on!:) Now I've obtained massage:                                                                                            XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/Edyta/Desktop/HTML/www.ogimet.com/cgi-bin/getsynop?begin=201511201200&state=Pol&lang=eng&block=12100. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.send @ jquery.js:9664

Comment: its because of google chrome?